# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_compile_flags'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to start the following tensorflow model word2vec example from the official github repository:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/embedding

The data preparation works:

```
curl http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip > text8.zip
unzip text8.zip
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/word2vec/source-archive.zip > source-archive.zip
unzip -p source-archive.zip  word2vec/trunk/questions-words.txt > questions-words.txt
rm text8.zip source-archive.zip
```

But the attempt to add the custom tensorflow operation fails like described in the following:

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_compile_flags'
```

The newest tensorflow version (v1.12.0) is installed via pip:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

The python version is v2.7.15.